# Word Usage: Appear

Tags: word-request, british-english, existentials

Is the following a correct sentence?

*For this reason, two paths between node A and B **appear** in the XXX graph.*

Actually, with the word **appear**, I try to mean Comes into Existence.

Is there any other word to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong whatsoever with using "appear" here.

You could also say:

*For this reason, two paths between node A and B  **are** in the XXX graph*

In either case, the meaning is the same.